# Init query in the StreamSets JDBC Query Consumer not working for Delete previous data

Tags: streamsets

I use **Streamsets** Data Collector to Load data from Stage 2 database tables (*JDBC Query Consumer*) using a query and Write loaded data to another Stage 2 Database table (*JDBC Producer*). I use Init Query as below to delete the previous records before loading data. **But this does not delete any record from the table.** It would be great if someone can help me.

[image]

Comment: 1. What SDC version?
2. Have you verified that your db user has authorisation to delete from that table?

Comment: StreamSets Data Collector 4.0.3, Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Init Query in the **JDBC Query Consumer** to delete previous records; it did not work. I removed the init query from the JDBC Query Consumer and added a **Start Event**. It deletes previous records, and the pipeline works as I expected. 
My question in the community: https://community.streamsets.com/show-us-your-pipelines-71/init-query-in-the-jdbc-query-consumer-not-working-for-delete-previous-data-2028?postid=4733#post4733

[image]

Comment: Good workaround. Meanwhile SDC 4.0.3 is more than 2 years old and is out of support. I suggest to get it upgraded.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will check that.

Comment: In fact, it's not a workaround, but the preferred solution. The purpose of Init Query in JDBC Query is to set the database session, not to change the state of the database. To change the state of the database use Start Event.

Comment: I found this in their official documentation: https://docs.streamsets.com/platform-datacollector/latest/datacollector/UserGuide/Origins/JDBCConsumer.html

Init Query: SQL query to perform immediately after the stage connects to the database. Use to set up the database session as needed.
For example, the following query deletes existing records in a table before writing new records: DELETE FROM <table>;

Comment: They are going to correct the documentation to make it clearer, and remove this "DELETE FROM" example (I work at Streamsets :) ).